# SmartGit: Mercurial Executable is not yet supported

Tags: mercurial, smartgit

I use SmartGit on Windows 7 for my projects and recently it told me the I need to download the new version as the current one is not supported. I did so but then this whole Mercurial thing started!

[image]

[image]

I then tried installing some older versions but it won't find the .exe file those folders.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/windows/, or your problem is where the Windows installs the Mercurial executable?

Comment: Also, give version 7.2 preview a try which supports Mercurial 3.7: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your smartgit version is too old. Use the preview version at https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/preview?file=smartgit/smartgit-win32-setup-jre-7.2-preview-4.zip